# Spring Thymeleaf with LocalDateTime problem

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, datetime, thymeleaf

I have problems with localdatetime attributes using Spring and Thymeleaf.

My code:

Event.java

```
public class Event {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    @Column(nullable=false)
    @NotNull(message="Name is required!")
    private String name;

    @Column(nullable=false)
    @NotNull(message="Time is required!")
    @DateTimeFormat(pattern = "MM.dd.yyyy. HH:mm")
    private LocalDateTime time;
}
```

EventController.java

```
...
@GetMapping("/eventEntry")
public String showForm(Model model) {

    model.addAttribute("event", new Event());

    return "eventEntry";
}

@PostMapping("/eventEntry")
public String processForm(@RequestParam("time") @DateTimeFormat(pattern = "MM.dd.yyyy. HH:mm") LocalDateTime time, 
        @Valid Event event, Errors errors, Model model) {

    if(errors.hasErrors()) {

        return "eventEntry";

    } else {

        eventList.add(event);

        eventRepository.save(event);

        model.addAttribute("event", event);
        model.addAttribute("time", time);
        model.addAttribute("listaDogadaja", listaDogadaja);

        return "output";
    }
}
```

eventEntry.html

```
<body>
    <h1>Event entry form</h1>

    <h3>New event</h3>

    <form method="POST" th:object="${event}">

        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="naziv">Name: </label>
            <input type="text" th:field="*{name}" />
            <span class="validation-error" th:if="${#fields.hasErrors('name')}" th:errors="*{name}">Name Error</span>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="time">Time: </label>
            <input type="datetime-local" th:field="*{time}" />
            <span class="validation-error" th:if="${#fields.hasErrors('time')}" th:errors="*{time}">Time Error</span>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            <input type="submit" th:value="Save">
            <input type="reset" class="btn btn-danger" th:value="Cancel">
        </div>

    </form>
</body>
```

When clicking the save button, I'm getting this exception:

```
Failed to convert value of type 'java.lang.String' to required type 'java.time.LocalDateTime';
nested exception is 
org.springframework.core.convert.ConversionFailedException: Failed to convert from type [java.lang.String] to type [@org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestParam @org.springframework.format.annotation.DateTimeFormat java.time.LocalDateTime] for value '05.14.2014. 1:00 PM';
nested exception is
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Parse attempt failed for value [05.14.2014. 1:00 PM]**
```

Why is that?

Comment: Your string contains AM/PM which is not present in your pattern

Answer (score 2):

Have a close look at this:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Parse attempt failed for value [05.14.2014. 1:00 PM]**
```

The time provided is : ***05.14.2014. 1:00 PM***

You need to change your code accordingly to support **AM/PM**: 
try:

```
...
@DateTimeFormat(pattern = "MM.dd.yyyy. HH:mm a")
private LocalDateTime time;
```

and

```
...
public String processForm(@RequestParam("time") @DateTimeFormat(pattern = "MM.dd.yyyy. HH:mm a") LocalDateTime time,
```

Here **a** means AM or PM.

for more have a look here: [format-time-12-hours-pattern](https://howtodoinjava.com/java/date-time/format-time-12-hours-pattern/)

Comment: now I'm getting the same exception, but with a value: 2019-05-29T09:27; I also tried changing the hour letters in the pattern from "HH" to "hh" like explained in the link you gave me (thank you btw, it was very helpful in terms of understanding), but with the same result

Comment: "2019-05-29T09:27" thats a different from defined: "MM.dd.yyyy. HH:mm a". So exception is expected. Does your application have to support many different time format?

Comment: no, it doesn't have to; tried changing the format to "yyyy.MM.dd. hh:mm a", still the same exception with the value from my upper comment...

Comment: see "2019-05-29T09:27" value does not matched with defined "yyyy.MM.dd. hh:mm a" either. Try changing to "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm" => for "2019-05-29T09:27"

Comment: still no luck; I've read that the HTML datetime-local element is not yet fully supported across all browsers, so I'm going to try a different approach, using separately date and time elements, but thank you for trying to solve my problem

Answer (score 0):

I needed this solution, to add a button (with function insert the current date and time)
or the event before the page was loaded

```
@DateTimeFormat(pattern="yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm")    
private LocalDateTime date;
```

In a thymeleaf *.html page

```
<input type="datetime-local" th:field="*{date}" id="input_data_name"/>
    <input type="button" value="Insert current date" id="button_id" />
```

javascript

```
var el_button = document.getElementById("button_id");
el_button.onclick = fillDateNow;
            
function fillDateNow() {
  var today = new Date().toISOString().substring(0, 16)
  document.getElementById("input_data_name").value = today;
}
</script>
```

if you want an extra seconds, try it

```
@DateTimeFormat(pattern="yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss")
private LocalDateTime date;
```

js

```
new Date().toISOString().substring(0, 19)
```

for just date it should be

```
@DateTimeFormat(pattern="yyyy-MM-dd")
private LocalDate date;
```

js

```
new Date().toISOString().substring(0, 10)
```